# How can I speed up this row-by-row operation in data.table

Tags: r, matrix, data.table

I have a `data.table` with `xe5` rows and approx 100 columns. I am looking to find the first 3 column index such that the value is not `NA` or `0`.

```
m <- matrix(rep(NA_integer_, 1e6), ncol=10)
for(i in 1:nrow(m)){
    set.seed(i);
    m[i, sample(1:10, 5)] =  1L:5L
}
DT <- data.table(m);
DT
        V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
     1: NA  5  1  2  3 NA  4 NA NA  NA
     2: NA  1 NA NA  3  5  2 NA NA   4
     3: NA  1  4  3 NA NA NA  2  5  NA
     4:  2  4  3 NA  5  1 NA NA NA  NA
     5:  5  4  1 NA NA NA  2  3 NA  NA
    ---                               
 99996: NA NA  2  3  5  1 NA NA  4  NA
 99997:  2 NA NA NA  1 NA NA  3  5   4
 99998:  5 NA  4  2 NA  1  3 NA NA  NA
 99999: NA  5 NA  1 NA  4 NA  2 NA   3
100000:  5 NA NA NA  2  3  1 NA NA   4

f <- function(x){return(list(which(!is.na(x) & x!=0L)[1:3L]))}

#Here is what apply do
system.time(test <- apply(m, FUN=f, MAR=1))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
       1.30        0.00        1.29
```

I find it very slow, this might not be a task for `data.table`, I am looking for a fast way of getting this answer (any method is welcome).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you could use the fact that `0 /0` is `NaN` which will also give `TRUE` for `is.na`. This'll reduce to condition to one `!is.na`. Second, you can vectorise using `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` that'll give a `row` and `col` index. We can use that to split by `row` and get the first three `col` values as follows:

```
system.time(tt <- data.table(which(!is.na(DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x/0)]), 
             arr.ind=TRUE), key="row")[, col[1:3], by="row"])
   user  system elapsed
  0.360   0.000   0.359
```

---

Edit: an alternative way:

```
DT <- DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) !is.na(x/0))]
out <- data.table(matrix(numeric(3e5), ncol=3))
system.time({    
for (i in as.integer(seq_along(DT))) {
    for (j in 1:3) {
        zeros <- .subset2(DT, i) & (out[[j]] == 0)
        out[zeros, names(out)[j] := i]
        DT[zeros, c(names(DT)[i]) := FALSE]
    }
}
})
```

Not sure if it's the fastest though.

Comment: first one is faster on my pc

Comment: getting rid of the `arrayInd` fluff will bring the first solution's time down by about 25% - `t = which(!is.na(m/0)); n = nrow(m); data.table(row = (t-1L) %% n + 1L, col = (t-1L) %/% n + 1L, key = 'row')[, col[1:3], by = row]`

Comment: Cool thanks, I still can't determine a rule when `apply(,MAR=1)` is faster than `data.table[,,by='row']`

Comment: @statquant apply coerces a data.frame (data.table) to a matrix, I think the memory issue will kick in before by = row becomes faster

Comment: On my real case (3e5*201) the alternative way is fastest, though >15seconds

Comment: @statquant, the alternative way is definitely slower. It takes 15 seconds with the first version and 27 seconds with the alternative one on my laptop. I'll see if it can be improved, now that I know the actual size of the problem. Note: eddi's optimisation reduces the runtime to around 10 seconds.